# Mysql show database sorted by creation date?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to get a list of MySQL databases ordered by creation date or last update date using a command?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this , if you want by update date you can order it by update_time

```
SELECT 
table_schema,
MAX(create_time) create_time,
MAX(update_time) update_time
FROM information_schema.tables
Group by TABLE_SCHEMA
Order by create_time desc
```

Comment: This works nicely. Combine that with one displaying `table_name` without a group by and max(), and you have detail

Comment: Worked great in 2017 still!

Answer (score 1):

Information_schema database contains meta data about databases:

```
SELECT distinct  table_schema
FROM   information_schema.tables
Order by update_time
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get list of database name from `information_schema` order by latest created date then check below code:

```
SELECT table_schema, MAX(create_time) create_time, MAX(update_time) update_time
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE create_time IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA
ORDER BY create_time DESC;
```

Result from above query, I see that there is some result with null value for create_time column. I assume that these records are may be created by default at mysql setup so make some pretty change.

Add `WHERE create_time IS NOT NULL` for filter above null create_time records:

```
SELECT table_schema, MAX(create_time) create_time, MAX(update_time) update_time
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE create_time IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA
ORDER BY create_time DESC;
```

NOTE: You can use `DISTINCT`, if you want only result with *table_schema* and don’t want to use `MAX()` and `GROUP BY`.

For this you need to use below code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  table_schema
FROM information_schema.tables
ORDER BY update_time
```

Let me know if there is any query from this.

I hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

considering the following schema and query

### Schema

```
create table xInnodb
(   i int 
); -- ie: engine=INNODB

create table xMyISAM
(   i int
)engine=MyISAM;

insert xInnodb (i) values (1);
insert xMyISAM (i) values (1);
-- or even update statements after the fact
```

### Query

```
SELECT table_schema,
table_name,
engine,
create_time,
update_time
FROM information_schema.tables
where TABLE_SCHEMA ='so_gibberish' -- my database name
and table_type='BASE TABLE' -- don't show views
Order by create_time desc;


+--------------+------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| table_schema | table_name | engine | create_time         | update_time         |
+--------------+------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| so_gibberish | xmyisam    | MyISAM | 2015-12-12 00:03:18 | 2015-12-12 00:10:54 |
| so_gibberish | xinnodb    | InnoDB | 2015-12-12 00:03:17 | NULL                |
+--------------+------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

You will find that innodb tables will have `update_time` as `NULL`

This can be read about in the Manual page entitled [The INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLES Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html):

> Beginning with MySQL 5.7.2, UPDATE_TIME displays a timestamp value for
>   the last UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE performed on InnoDB tables that are
>   not partitioned. Previously, UPDATE_TIME displayed a NULL value for
>   InnoDB tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to show all databases and create times...

> SELECT table_schema, create_time FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;

Note:  I haven't tested this